# How to set parent page in custom post type of other post type page?

Tags: wordpress, parent-child

I have created 3 custom post type. 1st post type is independent. I want to give parent 1st post type in 2nd. And the same, parent 2nd post type in 3rd post type. I am able to list the pages so user can select. all is good in back-end, but while we view the page, it is showing 'page not found'.